# Structure Theorem for finitely generated modules over PIDs

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $A$ be a real $4 \times 4$ matrix. Supose $i,-i$ are the eigenvalues of $A$. Show that there exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that $PAP^{-1}$ is either

$$\begin{pmatrix}
0&-1&0&0\\
1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&-1\\
0&0&1&0
\end{pmatrix}, 
\begin{pmatrix}
0&-1&0&0\\
1&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&-1\\
0&0&1&0
\end{pmatrix}.$$

My professor gives me some hints: The characteristic polynomial of $A$  is $f_A (x)=(x^2 +1)^2$ .  Therefore, by structure theorem of modules over a PID, $Im(A)$  is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}[x]/((x^2 +1)^2 )$  or $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2 +1) \times \mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2 +1)$ ...

Comment: Do you know Jordan normal form?

Comment: I have learnt smith normal form only...